# Nested function can't access global variable

Tags: typescript, angular5, nested-function

CODE:

```
public loaderShow = false;

Onsubmit(form:any):void{ 
    this.startLoader(this.endLoader);
}

public startLoader(ender) {
    this.loaderShow = true;
    setTimeout(ender, 2000);
}

public endLoader() {
    this.loaderShow = false;
    return this.loaderShow;
}
```

What I want to happen: 
    On submission of the form -> runs startLoader -> changes loaderShow to true
    
2 seconds later -> runs endLoader -> turns loaderShow to false again

What is happening: 
    On submission of the form -> runs startLoader -> changes loaderShow to true 
    2 seconds later -> runs endLoader -> can't access loaderShow (Perceives it as undefined)

What I need to do: 
    Find a way to let endLoader() be able to find loaderShow (but my attempts fail. I've tried passing it down through the functions as a parameter but I'm not sure how to make the changes to loaderShow global).

Comment: which "this." ?

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't realize that was within a class definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
setTimeout(ender, 2000);
```

to

```
setTimeout(ender.bind(this), 2000);
```

Or alternatively, change

```
this.startLoader(this.endLoader);
```

to

```
this.startLoader(this.endLoader.bind(this));
```

When you pass the function, it loses its context, so it needs to be bound to the class instance.

Comment: Legend. Thanks a lot!!